# A way to write this more concise? Need to check if a number is under 0

Tags: scala

```
val total_breaks = //a random number

total_breaks match {
  case i if(i < 0) => chartTemplate.setAttribute("totalBreaks", 0)
  case _ => chartTemplate.setAttribute("totalBreaks", total_breaks)
}
```

I was thinking there was a function in Scala that could shorten this. I thought `min` did this but I guess not. I can't seem to find documentation on `min`, `max`, etc.

Something like `total_breaks.min(0)`. Display 0 if under 0 if not display total_breaks.

Also is there a way do something like this

```
(4 + 5) match {
  case 0 => println("test")
  case _ => println(_) //i need to display the number passed into match?  Is this not  possible?
}
```

If I do `case i => println(i)` is that the same as `case _ =>` ?  Is that the fallback?

Comment: You are correct that `case i =>` will pick up all remaining cases with the input value as `i`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are methods `min` and `max` defined in [`GenTraversableOnce`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce), and thus available on sequences. You can use them as:

```
scala> List(1, -4, 0).min
resN: -4
```

There is also `min` and `max` defined in [`RichInt`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.runtime.RichInt), that work like operators on anything that can be converted to `RichInt`, typically your vanilla integers:

```
scala> -4 min 0
resN: -4
```

So if you want something that returns your number, say `x` if `x` is greater than `0` and `0` otherwise, you can write:

```
scala> x max 0
```

That means you can rewrite your pattern-matching as:

```
chartTemplate.setAttribute("totalBreaks", total_breaks max 0)
```

For your second question, `_` and `i` are both valid patterns that will match anything. The difference is that in the first case you do not bind what you have matched to a variable. Using `println(_)` is wrong, though; as such, it corresponds to an anonymous function that prints its first argument. So if you don't want to repeat the expression `(4 + 5)`, you should indeed write your pattern and code as:

```
case i => println(i)
```

Comment: Thanks.  So instead of min I had to use max.  Go figure.  Geez

Comment: There's also `math.min(Int,Int)`.